# How to exclude filenames with certain criteria when using forfiles

Tags: batch-file, automation, forfiles

I am trying to write a batch file that will move all CSV files that were last modified on or prior to 5/1/2021 from one folder to another. The problem is that I need to exclude any files that contain the word "report" in the file name. How would I accomplish this?

Here is what I have right now:
`forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.csv  /D -05/01/2021 /C "cmd /c move @file C:/Test2"`

Is there an easy way to do this? I have tried looking into how to exclude files based on criteria but can only really find how to do it by extension.

Comment: Maybe something with conditional execution would work. `echo @file|find /I /V  "report">nul &&move @file C:\Test2`

Comment: It would look a little like this: `@%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /S /M "*.csv" /P "C:\Test" /D "-05/01/2021" /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C 0x22Echo @file | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I \"report\" 1>NUL && Move /Y @Path \"C:\Test2\" 1>NUL0x22"`. _A similar method for excluding any file with the string `report` anywhere within its contents would be: `@%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /S /M "*.csv" /P "C:\Test" /D "-05/01/2021" /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C 0x22%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I \"report\" 0<@file 1>NUL && Move /Y @Path \"C:\Test2\" 1>NUL0x22"`._

Comment: Why not simply using an `if` condition: `forfiles /S /P "C:\Test" /M "*.csv" /D -05/01/2021 /C "cmd /D /V /C if @isdir==FALSE set 0x22NAME=@file0x22 & if 0x22!NAME!0x22==0x22!NAME:report=!0x22 move @file 0x22C:\Test20x22"`